# Null appears while parsing HTML

Tags: android, html, null, android-webview

I am trying to create dynamic *HTML* pages with *JSON* data, each time the application see a `#@`, it is replaced by a value. But when my page is loaded, I've got a `null` printed on the bottom. In the *HTML* code, the `null` is after the tag : `</html>`, at the all end of the document where there is any `#@`.

Maybe does it come from the `myOutWriter.append(mLine);` , but I did not succeed to fix it.

My code :

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("template_page.html"), "UTF-8"));

myFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  + "/Viz/HTML/template_page.html");

myFile.createNewFile();
fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

mLine = reader.readLine();

String[] replace = { colorHex,...self_job_slug, colorString};

while (mLine != null) {
    mLine = reader.readLine();
    if (mLine != null && mLine.contains("%@")) {
        mLine = mLine.replace("%@", replace[count]);
        count++;
    }
    myOutWriter.append(mLine);
}
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();

webView.loadUrl("file://" 
                + android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Viz/HTML/template_page.html");

reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get `null` since you read a new line after you checked if mLine is `null`.

Let's say you are at the last line and `mLine != null` is true. You enter your `if-statement` and read another line (You where on the last line), the new line does not exist and `mLine` will become null.

You could do it in other ways (`do{}while()`), but to alter your code as little as possible I think you should read a new line last in your `while-loop`.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem !